# Angular - ngRepeat Order before Filter (pagination + ordering)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, website-deployment

I have an ngRepeat `ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:tableOrdering | filter:currentPage"`

- **orderBy:tableOrdering** will return integers from 1 to 1000 and order in that fashion.
- **filter:currentPage** will return the first page of results from $scope.rows (bool)

Because `filter:currentPage` always returns the elements from $scope.rows, which is not ordered, only the results on that (filtered) page will be ordered.

Is there a way to run the OrderBy FIRST so that it will order all of the rows then filter by currentPage after it is sorted?

CODE EXAMPLE: http://plnkr.co/edit/CamEiYIxyW5TaUPgmHxD

Comment: Whats the problem? http://plnkr.co/edit/cRA0EuiEvUzwaLeO4ptr?p=preview  filter do not reorder elements and applied after orderBy...

Answer (score 1):

Using the `prototype.some()` function, gave back the index (offset) of the original array of items.  This causes a problem because we need the index of the sorted array.  If we restructure the function to use an index in relation to the order function it works great.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:tableOrdering  | filter:currentPage">
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'StackOverflow';
  $scope.items = [
      {id : 1, value : 2},
      {id : 2, value : 6},
      {id : 3, value : 5},
      {id : 4, value : 1},
      {id : 5, value : 0},
      {id : 6, value : 6},
      {id : 7, value : 8},
      {id : 8, value : 4},
      {id : 9, value : 6},
      {id : 10, value : 3}
    ];

  $scope.pagination = {
        limit: 3, // ITems per page
        current: 0, // Current page (page - 1)
        asc: true, // Asc Vs Desc
        index: 0 // Count Variable for ordering/pagination
    };

    $scope.setPage = function(page) {
      $scope.pagination.current = page;
    }

    $scope.tableOrdering = function(item) {
        $scope.pagination.index = 0; // Resets index for counting
            if ($scope.pagination.asc) {
                return parseFloat(item.value);
            }
            else {
                return parseFloat(item.value) * (-1);
            }
    };

    $scope.currentPage = function(item) {
      for (var k = 0; k < $scope.items.length; k++) {
        if (item.id == $scope.items[k].id) {
          $scope.pagination.index++;
              if (  ($scope.pagination.limit * $scope.pagination.current)           <= $scope.pagination.index - 1 &&
                    ($scope.pagination.limit * ($scope.pagination.current + 1) - 1) >= $scope.pagination.index - 1) {

                 // On page
                 return true;
            }
            else {
              // Not on page
              return false;
            }
      }
      }

      // Fallback
      return false;
    };

});
```

**Plunker link** : http://plnkr.co/edit/sFvM9Nc65DPCwLy5lofE?p=preview